# Cast Keys object to enum Direction object?

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I've created a enum `Direction` like so:

```
enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }
```

Now these directions get called on arrow key presses. What I have now in my `KeyDown` event is this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
{
    moveDirection = Direction.Up;
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
{
    moveDireciton = Direction.Left;
}
else if ...
```

Is it possible to create my own cast like `(Direction)Keys.Up`?

I know I could just create a static method `static Direction CastKeysToDirection(Keys k);` and I'm fine with this, but I'm just curious if there's a way to implement our own casts in c#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define your enum as

```
enum Direction {
    Up = Keys.Up,
    Down = Keys.Down,
    Left = Keys.Left,
    Right = Keys.Right
}
```

then your cast `(Direction)Keys.Up` should work by virtue of the fact that the numerical value underlying `Keys.Up` is the same as the numerical value underlying `Direction.Up`.

Sadly, though, you can't provide a true `explicit` or `impilcit` cast on an `enum` like you can on a `class`.

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

- Just cast, if you're *sure* the values match (e.g. because you've created the `Direction` enum using `Keys.Up` etc as the values):

  ```
  moveDirection = (Direction) e.KeyCode;
  ```
- Create a dictionary:

  ```
  private static readonly Dictionary<Keys, Direction> KeyToDirection =
      new Dictionary<Keys, Direction>
      {
          { Keys.Up, Direction.Up },
          { Keys.Left, Direction.Left },
          ...
      };
  ```

  Then just look up the key that's been pressed in the dictionary. (Use `TryGetValue` to look up a `Keys` - use the return value to detect keys which aren't present in the dictionary.)

The latter gives a more flexible approach, of course. It allows you to have multiple keys all mapping to the same direction, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit casting is not possible to *enum*, but you can use *implicit* operator in *class* implementation and then maybe use some benefits of polymorphism and encapsulation in further working (Included suggestion of @Chris Sinclair):

```
public abstract class Direction
{
    public static implicit operator Direction(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                return Up.Instance;
            case Keys.Down:
                return Down.Instance;
            case Keys.Left:
                return Left.Instance;
            case Keys.Right:
                return Right.Instance;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}

public class Up : Direction
{
    private static readonly Up _Instance = new Up();
    public static Up Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }

    private Up() {}
}

public class Down : Direction
{
    private static readonly Down _Instance = new Down();
    public static Down Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }

    private Down() {}
}

public class Left : Direction
{
    private static readonly Left _Instance = new Left();
    public static Left Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }

    private Left() {}
}

public class Right : Direction
{
    private static readonly Right _Instance = new Right();
    public static Right Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }

    private Right() {}
}
```

The use case:

```
Keys key = Keys.Up;
Direction direction = key; // Legal

if (direction == Up.Instance)
{
    // Do something
}

// Or add abstract methods to Direction class and invoke direction.DoWork()
```

Comment: +1 If you're going to go this route, I'd rather declare a private constructor on `Direction` and define 4 `public static readonly` fields on it for each direction rather than 4 subclasses and generating new instances for each one when used.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: You're right. I included your suggestion, but preserving the subclasses. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I meant more like this: `public class Direction { private Direction(){} public static readonly Direction Up = new Direction(); public static readonly Direction Down = new Direction(); public static readonly Direction Left = new Direction(); public static readonly Direction Right = new Direction(); }` Then there's no need for subclassing, comparisons are like `myDirection == Direction.Up`, and you can add other convenience or Enum-like methods on `Direction` as well like: `public static Direction[] GetValues() { return new[]{Up, Down, Left, Right}; }`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I know, but I like more current option which provides more functionality.